# `requestCursorUpdates` fails without logging on every jetpack compose `TextField`

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I call this on any Jetpack Compose `TextField`:

```kotlin
        if (ctx.currentInputConnection.requestCursorUpdates(CURSOR_UPDATE_MONITOR)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "request for cursor updates succeeded, cursor updates will be provided")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "request for cursor updates failed, cursor updates will not be provided")
        }
```

It fails, IE logs `Request for cursor updates failed`.

Cursor updates are being picked up fine on any non jetpack-compose `TextField` .

Has anyone got `requestCursorUpdates` working with Jetpack Compose?